# how do I fetch and combine data from MySQL then insert into array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

This question is quite specific for my needs, hence I can't find the best way to do this.

What I would like to do is fetch `name` and `surname` from the table `people` and combine both into an array to end up with such results:

`"Bob Jones","Tony Wright",`.. etc.

I'm using PDO for this. Here is what I have:

```
$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);

// connect to PDO
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new", "root", "root", $attrs);

// the following tells PDO we want it to throw Exceptions for every error.
// this is far more useful than the default mode of throwing php errors
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$conn = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name, surname FROM people");

$conn->execute();
$results = $conn->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $row){

    $fullName = $row['name'] . "," . $row['surname'];

    print_r($fullName);
}
```

I have tried a few things, I'm just stuck with this code at minute. Any help, or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: What error you are facing in the above code ?

Comment: and you dont need print_r for $fullName.just echo

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui im faced with a string like this: `BobJones,TonyWright` - no spaces..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
foreach($results as $row) {
   $arr[] = "{$row['name']},{$row['surname']}";
}
echo implode($arr);
```

Comment: This was sufficient enough for me to make my own code to resolve my problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also resolve this problem in SQL, so foreach would not be needed any more.

Just replace

```
SELECT name, surname FROM people
```

with

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', name, surname) FROM people
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you’ve fetched the rows from the database, you need to loop over the result set and assign the combined name to a new array:

```
<?php

// result set from database
$results = $conn->fetchAll();

// create an empty array to store our names
$names = array();

// loop over result set and add entry to $names array
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $names[] = $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['surname'];
}

print_r($names);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullname =array();
foreach($results as $row){
        $fullName = $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname'];
}
print_r($fullname);
```